# How to design a Springbatch job which fetches records from DB in batches and run multiple processor and writer in parallel

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, spring-batch, jobs

**Scenario:** Read records from DB and create 4 different output files from it.

**Tech Stack:**

- Springboot 2.x
- springBatch  4.2.x
- ArangoDB 3.6.x

**Current Approach:** SpringBatch job which has the below steps in sequence:

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("alljobs")
      .start(step("readAllData")) //reads all records from db, stores it in Obj1 (R1)
      .next(step("processData1")) //(P1)
      .next(step("writer1"))      // writes it to file1(W1)
      .next(step("reader2"))      // reads the same obj1(R2)
      .next(step("processor2"))   // processes it (P2)
      .next(step("writer2"))      // writes it to file1(W2)
      .next(step("reader3"))      // reads the same obj1 (R3)
      .next(step("processor3"))   // processes it (P3)
      .next(step("writer3"))      // writes it to file1(W3)
      .next(step("reader4"))      // reads the same obj1(R4)
      .next(step("processor4"))   // processes it (P4)
      .next(step("writer4"))      // writes it to file1 (W4)
      .build()
```

**Problem:** Since the volume of data coming from DB is HUGE, > 200,000 records, hence now we are fetching the records via cursor in a batch of 10,000 records.

**Target state of the job:** A reader job which fetches the records from DB via a cursor in batch of 1000 records:

1. For each batch of 1000 records I have to run processor and writer for the same.
2. Also, since for all the rest 3 processor and writers, the data set will be the same (`Obj1` which will be fetched from the cursor), triggering them in parallel.

```
Reader1() {
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
          Obj1 = cursor.next();

          a) P1(Obj1);  |    c) R2(Obj1); |    c) R3(Obj1);  |   c) R4(Obj1);   || 
          b) W1(Obj1);  |    d) P2(Obj1); |    d) P3(Obj1);  |   d) P4(Obj1);   || All these running in parallel.
                        |    e) W2(Obj1); |    e) W3(Obj1);  |   e) W4(Obj1);   ||
    }
}
```

Below are approaches that popped in my mind:

- Invoke the Job inside the cursor itself and execute all steps `P1....W4` inside the cursor iteration by iteration.
- Invoke a job which has first step as `Reader1`, and then inside the cursor, invoke another `subJob` which has all these `P1....W4` in parallel, since we can not go out of the cursor.

Kindly suggest the best way to implement.

Thanks in Advance.

**Update:**

I was trying to make the steps(P1....W4) inside My Reader1 step in a loop , but am stuck with the implementation as everything here is written as a Step and am not sure how to call multiple steps inside R1 step in a loop . I tried using a Decider , putting P1...W4 in a Flow(`flow`) :

```
   flowbuilder.start(step("R1"))
         .next(decider())
         .on(COMPLETED).end()
         .from(decider())
         .on(CONTINUE)
         .flow(flow)

job.start(flow)
   .next(flow).on("CONTINUE").to(endJob()).on("FINISHED").end()
   .end()
   .build()
```

But I am not able to go back to the next cursor iterations , since the cursor iteration is there in the R1 step only.
I also tried to put all steps R1...W4(including Reader1) in the same flow, but the flow ended up throwing cyclic flow error .

Kindly suggest what should be a better way to implement this? How to make all the other steps called in parallel inside the cursor iterating in R1 step.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your comment. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using 4 parallel steps is a good option for you. Even if you would have 4 threads reading from the same data, you should benefit from parallel steps during the processing/writing phases. This should definitely perform better than 4 steps in sequence. BTW, 200k records is not that much (of course it depends on the record size and how it is mapped, but I think this should be ok, reading data is never the bottleneck).

It's always about trade-offs.. Here I'm trading a bit of read duplication for a better overall throughput thanks to parallel steps. I would not kill my self to make sure items are read only once and complicate things.

A good analogy of such a trade-off in the database world is accepting some data duplication in favor of faster queries (think of NoSQL design where it is sometime recommended to duplicate some data to avoid expensive joins).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @Mahmoud . However, even if the same obj is used by all 4 Processor.. the object to be written is different in all 4 cases . e.g. P1 reads same obj1 .. but creates objP1 which is then written by W1.... P2 reads same obj1 but created objP2 which is then written by W2 .. so, in this case all my 4 processors are different in nature .

Comment: ok, that's not what I understood from your example: `b) W1(Obj1); e) W2(Obj1); |    e) W3(Obj1);  |   e) W4(Obj1);`. This, for me, means writing the same object 4 times to different destinations, hence my suggestion about a composite writer. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Muhamoud for the updated answer, it helped . I was trying to implement similar logic but facing issues with the same .I am stuck with how to implement the decider and flow concetps here , so need some help . I have updated my question with the current logic that I am trying . Is there any other way/concept in springboot that i should approach this implementation with?

Comment: Please note that accepting an answer is different from upvoting it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally designed the solution:

So, I re-framed the whole flow from a Tasklet based approach to an Orchestrated Chunk Based approach .

Job will have 1 step called - fetchProcessAndWriteData .

```
jobBuilderFactory.get("allChunkJob")
      .start(step("fetchProcessAndWriteData"))
      .next(step("updatePostJobRunDetails")) 
      .build()
```

fetchProcessAndWriteData : will have a reader , masterProcessor and masterWriter with a chunk size of 10,000 .

```
steps
        .get("fetchProcessAndWriteData")
        .chunk(BATCHSIZE)
        .reader(chunkReader)
        .processecor(masterProcessor)
        .writer(masterWriter)
        .listener(listener())
        .build()
```

**chunkReader**- reader data in chunks from the database cursor and pass it on to the masterProcessor .

**masterProcessor** - accepts data one by one and pass the records to all the other processecors - P1, P2, P3, P4 
    and stores the processed data in a compositeResultBean .

CompositeResultBean consists of data holders for all 4 types of records .

```
List<Record> recordType1.
    List<Record> recordType2.
    List<Record> recordType3.
    List<Record> recordType4.
```

This bean is then returned from the process method of the masterProcessor .

```
public Object process(Object item){
     .. 
     bean.setRecordType1(P1.process(item));
     bean.setRecordType2(P2.process(item));
     bean.setRecordType3(P3.process(item));
     bean.setRecordType4(P4.process(item));
     return bean;
    }
```

**masterWriter** - this step accepts a List of records i.e. list of compositeResultBean here. Iterate on the list of bean and call the respective 
    writers W1, W2,W3,W4 writer() method with the data held in each of compositeResultBean attributes .

public void write(List list) {

```
list.forEach(record -> {
    W1.write(isInitialBatch,list.getRecordType1());
    W2.write(isInitialBatch,list.getRecordType2());
    W3.write(isInitialBatch,list.getRecordType3());
    W4.write(isInitialBatch,list.getRecordType4());
    }); 
  }
```

These whole steps are carried in a batch of 10k records and write the data into the file .

Another challenge that I faced during writing the File was that I would have to replace the already existing file for the very first time the record are written ,but have to append for the later ones in the same file .
    I solved this problem by overring **chunkListener** in the masterWriter - where I pulled in the batch # and set a static flag **isInitialBatch** defaulting to TRUE.
    This variable is set inside the

```
beforeChunk() 
if chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getCommitCount()==0 as TRUE , else FALSE .
```

The same boolean is passed int he FileWriter which opens the file in append - TRUE or FALSE mode .

```
W1.write(isInitialBatch,list.getRecordType1());
```